# Devise & Google OAuth2 : could not determine client ID from request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, google-authentication

I followed the tutorial at : [Integrating Social Login with rails](https://scotch.io/tutorials/integrating-social-login-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application)

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', '~> 1.0'

group :development do
 gem 'dotenv', '~> 2.2.1'
end
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, '*client_id*', '*client_secret*'
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['*client_id*'], ENV['*client_secret*'], scope: 'userinfo.email,userinfo.profile',provider_ignores_state: true
end
```

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: '_devise-omniauth_session'
```

**app/controllers/users/omniauth_controller.rb**

```
  # google callback
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.create_from_google_data(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Google') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in through Google. Please register or try signing in later.'
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in. Please register or try signing in later.'
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
```

**.env**

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID: *client_id*
GOOGLE_APP_SECRET: *client_secret*
```

**Google Console Settings:**
[image]

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

After clicking on signin with google, redirected link is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=*client_id*&destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&approval_state=!ChQycF81dk1UeGg2WjRPTEdOZ18yNRIfNHhGdkhaUmowalVZOEhuU1JuY2dubXAtOXV2ZU5CWQ%E2%88%99AB8iHBUAAAAAWvaMkkzg-COYktH8xFkYhq5k9iV0uBKM&xsrfsig=AHgIfE9ctg3rKpRUm7927RhRh8pzq2rk3w&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

**After selecting account, the page redirects back to login again.
The console logs are as shown below:**

```
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=6396a69e62eea2e698b1e03dc8483005bf167272f09db8e0&code=4/AADTB7
PfvgUIUKZqtQs2r5ANRqxBvbm79WhhVdsSp-ZKsvm11OIKpOu_FlrzdHCUpRnE7vYfifM7Wu25IR_E31k" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-11 12:14
:20 +0530
(google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
(google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
(google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_request: Could not determine cli
ent ID from request.
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",

  "error_description" : "Could not determine client ID from request."
}
Processing by Users::OmniauthController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"6396a69e62eea2e698b1e03dc8483005bf167272f09db8e0", "code"=>"4/AADTB7PfvgUIUKZqtQs2r5ANRqxBv
bm79WhhVdsSp-ZKsvm11OIKpOu_FlrzdHCUpRnE7vYfifM7Wu25IR_E31k"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**I have tried several solutions online but none of them worked. 
Thanks in Advance !**

Comment: I see in your devise initializer `ENV['*client_id*'], ENV['*client_secret*']` . Shouldn't it be `ENV['GOOGLE_APP_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_APP_SECRET']` , as described in your .env file ?

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye  are'nt they same ?

Comment: what your .env does is something like `ENV['GOOGLE_APP_SECRET'] = '123456789'`
So when you do in your code `ENV['GOOGLE_APP_SECRET']` you get `=> "123456789" `
But when you do in your code `ENV['123456789']` you get `=> nil `
The value is not the key
`ENV[key]=value`

Comment: by the way , using  \*client_id\* & \*client_secret\* directly in your code ( like in your `initializers/omniauth.rb` )  completely make your .env file useless, as you're exposing the values in code. (visible on github for example)

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye  so would you please show me an example env file here ? as im really confused of key and value here.

Comment: For example a .env file should look like this:
https://pastebin.com/XzCrap6j

And then in your code you need to use it like that:
https://pastebin.com/n4GtWrxv